# Comment on appelle un 'bread clip' en francais ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

Quel est le nom de la chose qui maintient les paquets de brioche / pains de mie fermés ?

[image: breadclip]

Comment: That is not called a bread "clip". It's a tie. Ties and clips are not exactly the same.

Comment: This picture is not showing a bread clip but a  [twist tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_tie). [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_clip) is what a bread clip is. [Here](https://www.instructables.com/10-Ingenious-Bread-Clip-and-Twist-Tie-Life-Hacks/) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En France, je dirais que cet objet n'a forcément de nom. A l'oral, ça pourrait souvent donner ceci :

> Le truc/bidule/zigouigoui qui ferme le sachet du pain.

Si on veut utiliser un seul mot, on peut dire, d'une manière générale (ne donne pas d'indication sur la forme) :

> Une **attache**.

ou bien, s'il s'agit de fil de fer plastifié (et non ceux aplatis comme sur la photo) :

> Un **lien**.

...mais cela sonne un peu technique pour un utilisation à l'oral (plutôt quelque chose que l'on imagine dans un mode d'emploi par ex.)

Enfin, il doit y avoir du jargon techniques précis chez les industriels de l'emballage. Voici ce que j'ai trouvé pour les liens à torsader :
https://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=55150

> ces liens en plastique armé sont aussi appelés **liens cellotwist** ou encore **attaches cellotwist**.

Comment: A tie in English is une attache.

Answer (score 5):

En plus de ce qui précède, c'est un objet avec des fils de fer dans un morceau de plastique qui s'apparente techniquement à un [*twist tie*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twist_tie) c'est-à-dire une *ligature* ou un *lien torsadé* ([GDT](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2088707), [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=TWIST%20TIE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)). On a aussi l'*attache pour sac* pour le petit carré « de plastique à insertion latérale servant à la fermeture par pincement des sacs de plastique » (GDT).

Answer (score 2):

Au Canada, ceux en forme de "plaque" échancrées sont appelés des [attaches à pain](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1086135/attaches-pain-languette-chaise-roulante-clermont-bonnenfant).

Comment: Une attache ici aussi.

Answer (score 2):

Chez nous, nous appelons ça un "écoutilleur."

Cela vient d'Auvergne. Je n'ai pas d'explication plus précises. C'est un mot qu'emploi ma grand mère, qui est originaire de Vollore Ville.

Comment: Où est-ce ?  La réponse n'est pas claire avec si peu de détails.  Voici le [tour] du site et le centre [help].  Bienvenue sur French language SE.

Comment: Excusez-moi. Cela vient d'Auvergne. Je n'ai pas d'explication plus précises. C'est un mot qu'emploi ma grand mère, qui est originaire de Vollore Ville

Answer (score 1):

J'appelle ça une "chechette"

Comment: Il y a une source ?  Voici le [tour] du site et le [help]